# Opening and closing div based on loop

Tags: php, html, wordpress, loops, count

I know that maybe this is not a WP exclusively related question but I think the fault here is the loop and I am missing something.
I am trying to create a custom 'archive' page where, using the loop, I would like to style my posts in group of 4.
Right now I have 10 posts in this category and I don't think they will be much more but I can't force anything because they can increase or decrease easily.

```
<div id="bun" class="bun sezmenu">
<?php $catquery = new WP_Query( 'category_name=bun&&posts_per_page=-1&&nopaging=true'); $et_npb = 1;$id = 37;$category = get_category($id);$count = $category->category_count;?>
<?php if ($catquery->have_posts() ) : while($catquery->have_posts()) : $catquery->the_post();?>
    <?php if ($et_npb === 1 || $et_npb % 5 === 0 ){ echo '<div class="row">' ;};?>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="list__item list__item_ajax">
            <a href="" title="<?php the_title();?>" class="umodal__open" umodal-src="<?php the_permalink();?>">
                <img class="lazyload rounded-circle"
                     src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/img/bn/bun.png"
                     data-src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/img/bun.png"
                     height="128" width="128"
                     alt="<?php the_title();?>" />
            </a>
        </div><!-- list__item list__item_ajax -->
    </div>
<?php ++$et_npb; if ($et_npb % 5 == 0 || $et_npb == $count){echo '</div>';};
endwhile;endif;?>
```

As you can see in the image below there is something wrong and I can't figure out what.
Am I correctly using the function to count all the posts in this category?

[image: First row is correct (4 elements), second row is wrong (5 elements)]

I tried also this tool to try to understand if the divs are left open or they are closed.

```
<divid="bun" class="bun sezmenu">
  |<divclass="row">
  |       |<divclass="col">
  |       |       |<divclass="list__item list__item_ajax">
  |       |       |</div>
  |       |</div>
  |       |<divclass="col">
  |       |       |<divclass="list__item list__item_ajax">
  |       |       |</div>
  |       |</div>
  |       |<divclass="col">
  |       |       |<divclass="list__item list__item_ajax">
  |       |       |</div>
  |       |</div>
  |       |<divclass="col">
  |       |       |<divclass="list__item list__item_ajax">
  |       |       |</div>
  |       |</div>
  |</div>
  |<divclass="row">
  |       |<divclass="col">
  |       |       |<divclass="list__item list__item_ajax">
  |       |       |</div>
  |       |</div>
  |       |<divclass="col">
  |       |       |<divclass="list__item list__item_ajax">
  |       |       |</div>
  |       |</div>
  |       |<divclass="col">
  |       |       |<divclass="list__item list__item_ajax">
  |       |       |</div>
  |       |</div>
  |       |<divclass="col">
  |       |       |<divclass="list__item list__item_ajax">
  |       |       |</div>
  |       |</div>
  |       |<divclass="col">
  |       |       |<divclass="list__item list__item_ajax">
  |       |       |</div>
  |       |</div>
  |</div>
  |<divclass="row">
  |       |<divclass="col">
  |       |       |<divclass="list__item list__item_ajax">
  |       |       |</div>
  |       |</div>
  |</div>
  |<divid="piadina" class="piadina sezmenu">
  |</div>
  |<divid="crepe" class="crepe sezmenu">
  |</div>
  |<divid="dolci" class="dolci sezmenu">
  |</div>
  |<divumodal-id="umodal-1" class="umodal">
  |       |<divclass="umodal__inner">
  |       |       |<divclass="umodal__content">
  |       |       |</div>
  |       |</div>
  |</div>
```

And it says that I am missing somewhere 1  tags but this is obvious because my loop doesn't close correctly all the divs.

This is how it should work but I can't figure it out and it can't stay 'hardcode':

```
<div id="bun" class="bun sezmenu">
<?php $catquery = new WP_Query( 'category_name=bun&&posts_per_page=-1&&nopaging=true'); $et_npb = 1;$id = 37;$category = get_category($id);$count = $category->category_count;?>
<?php if ($catquery->have_posts() ) : while($catquery->have_posts()) : $catquery->the_post();?>
<?php if ($et_npb === 1 || $et_npb === 5 || $et_npb ===9){;?><div class="row"><?php };?>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="list__item list__item_ajax">
            <a href="" title="<?php the_title();?>" class="umodal__open" umodal-src="<?php the_permalink();?>">
                <img class="lazyload rounded-circle"
                     src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/img/bn/bun.png"
                     data-src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/img/bun.png"
                     height="128" width="128"
                     alt="<?php the_title();?>" />
            </a>
        </div><!-- list__item list__item_ajax -->
    </div>
    <?php ++$et_npb; if ($et_npb === 5 || $et_npb === 9 ||  $et_npb === $count+1){echo '</div>';};
        endwhile;endif;?>
</div><!-- .sezmenu -->
```

[image: This is what I would like to achieve]

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the simplest solution is simply out of reach, but this time, I've found mine!
What do you thing about it? Can it be improved?

```
<div id="bun" class="bun sezmenu">
<?php $catquery = new WP_Query( 'category_name=bun&&posts_per_page=-1&&nopaging=true'); $et_npb = 0;$id = 37;$category = get_category($id);$count = $category->category_count;?>
<?php if ($catquery->have_posts() ) : while($catquery->have_posts()) : $catquery->the_post();?>
<?php if (($et_npb === 0) || ($et_npb %4 == 0)){;?><div class="row"><?php };?>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="list__item list__item_ajax">
            <a href="" title="<?php the_title();?>" class="umodal__open" umodal-src="<?php the_permalink();?>">
                <img class="lazyload rounded-circle"
                     src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/img/bn/bun.png"
                     data-src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/img/bun.png"
                     height="128" width="128"
                     alt="<?php the_title();?>" />
            </a>
        </div><!-- list__item list__item_ajax -->
    </div>
    <?php ++$et_npb; if ( ($et_npb %4 == 0) ||  ($et_npb === $count)){echo '</div>';};
        endwhile;endif;?>
</div><!-- .sezmenu -->
```